# Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method when running Outlook from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to get Outlook to fetch a mail template I have stored in the folder "Templates" from a Excel VBA code, but get the error 438 code on the line "Mapp = Application.GetNamespace..." in the GetMailTemplate-function.

I have added both Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library & Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library to Excel VBAProject

This is my code:

```
Sub Email()
Dim AMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set AMailItem = GetMailTemplate("Mall Confidential")
With AMailItem
    .To = "a.b@c.com"
    .Subject = "Email Test using VBA"
    .Body = "Test"
    .Display
    .Send
End With   
Set AMailItem = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetMailTemplate(Headline As String) As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Mapp As Outlook.Folder
Dim OutMail2 As Outlook.MailItem
Mapp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Folders("Templates")
For Each OutMail2 In Mapp.Items                 
    Debug.Print OutMail2.Subject                    'Print to immediate window
    If OutMail2.Subject = Headline Then             
        Set GetMailTemplate = OutMail2.Copy         
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: That's because `Application` refers to the Excel application. You need a reference to an existing or new instance of the Outlook application.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of how that code part would look like?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application

Comment: `Dim app as Outlook.Application`, `Set app = New Outlook.Application`.

Comment: Besides what BigBen remarked, your "Templates" folder does not exist in `Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)`. You can check that using `Debug.Print Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Folders.Count`. I'm afraid, it will return zero...  Usually, Outlook saves your templates in this path: `"C:\Users\Your_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"`. If you have any .oft file there, you can iterate between the items in this folder, I think... Or you can save them wherever you want and then use that custom path.

Comment: I tried it in the part:
Function GetMailTemplate(Headline As String) As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim app As Outlook.Application
        Set app = New Outlook.Application
    Dim Mapp As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutMail2 As Outlook.MailItem
    Mapp = app.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Folders("Templates")....
But get the Automation error ’440’ the action failed. An object was not found